# PostgreSQL HA + Load Balancing + Pooling setup

Tags: postgresql, pgbouncer, pgpool

I'm facing dilemma regarding which method to achieve HA + Load Balancing + Pooling for postgreSQL.

Currently I'm in the phase of POC, and I had setup a cluster of 3 nodes which consists of 1 master and 2 slave. This cluster also setup with repmgr for auto-failover.

So now I don't know which tool to achieve load balance + pooling...

1. Can I say repmgr already cover the HA part?
2. I heard repmgr not work well with pgpool, is that true?
3. pbBouncer only support pooling but no load balance right?
4. Any recommendation on which should I use in this case? repmgr + pgpool or repmgr + pgbounce?

Thank you.

Comment: I believe you should use https://www.haproxy.org/ plus either https://github.com/yandex/odyssey or https://github.com/agroal/pgagroal, plus https://patroni.readthedocs.io/en/latest/